# how to get particular words with dotted lines in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following text:

1. I ate yogurt in the morning
2. yogurt was very nice
3. eating yogurt in the morning is healthy

I want to have the word "yogurt" underlined with a dotted line.

Just underlining is easy with the `<u>` tag, but I am confused how to get particular word to be underlined with dots.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is to use a dotted [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-style).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HhRT5/

```
<ol>
    <li>I ate <span class="yogurt">yogurt</span> in the morning</li>
    <li><span class="yogurt">yogurt</span> was very nice</li>
    <li>eating <span class="yogurt">yogurt</span> in the morning is healthy</li>
</ol>

.yogurt {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #aaa;
}
```

- [Possible future options with `text-decoration-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-decoration-style)